# uint8_t* - Pointer to the RGB Image address

Tags: c, image, pointers

I am trying to use this function, in order to display image on the STM board's 240x240 LCD: 
`void BSP_LCD_DrawRGBImage(uint16_t Xpos, uint16_t Ypos, uint16_t Xsize, uint16_t Ysize, uint8_t * pdata)`

While `Xpos`, `Ypos`, `Xsize` and `Ysize` are obvious, I don't know what should I do with the last parameter `uint8_t * pdata`. [Documentation](https://documentation.help/STM3210C_EVAL-BSP-Driver/group__STM3210C__EVAL__LCD__Exported__Functions.html#ga0b9ea336a06190c37f9f744d6d4b06e2) says, that it has to be *Pointer to the RGB Image address*. How can I get the address of image stored in the flash memory, using `uint8_t *` type and use it in this function? What pointer operation should I do? How can I create pointer to a file?

The board I'm using is [DISCO-F413ZH](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Discovery-F413H/#overview)

Comment: Besides the problem with JPEG compression vs. raw image data, your function wants to get an image address, not a file. Even if your file contains the proper data (instead of some jpeg stuff), you need to load it into memory first.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel data is in the 565 format (16 bits). It means thar R is 5 bits, G is  6 bits and B 5 bits long.

if your image is lets say defined like this

```
const unt16_t image[] = { /*a lots of numbers*/ };
```

Then to avoid compiler warning you need to cast this array pointer to the `uint8_t *`

```
 BSP_LCD_DrawRGBImage(xpos, ypos, xsize, ysize, (uint8_t *)image);
```

STM guys did not hear about the const correctness or `void *` pointers :)

## edit:

From the OPs comments. You need to convert JPG file to the 565 RGB file first. Many graphics design programs do it - for example GIMP. Then you need to convert it to the the `C` file. (you can use many available programs for example https://www.segger.com/free-utilities/bin2c/). It is possible to convert the file directly to the object file - but I personally prefer to have the C source file.

Comment: Does it mean, that I can't just set the address to file, like JPG? I have to set each pixel separately?

Comment: @KamilSerafin what file in the flash memory (where the program is stored)? If you mean SD card - do not call it flash memory when asking uC questions as it only causes confusion

Comment: The image is stored in board's flash memory (1.5 Mbytes), same as the program itself. I haven't used SD card yet.

Comment: @KamilSerafin so what is the problem - I have shown you how to use it.

Comment: @KamilSerafin you cant directly store jpeg images. You need jpeg decoding libraries or JPEG capable STM32 uC. But you can convert it to the RGB image on your PC